# Did the Community user stop automatically demoting [featured] posts after 30 days?

Tags: support, community-user, featured-tag

I recall that once upon a time the Community user removes the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag from posts 30 days after it's added ([example](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/2321/revisions), see revision 4). However, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/336177/revisions) question has been featured for more than 40 days and the Community user hasn't kicked in to remove the featured status. Has the behavior changed since?

Comment: If even the Community user has suspended their activity on this site, we're in trouble.

Comment: I believe featuring / unfeaturing became a wholly manual process when they removed HMP.

Comment: @yivi Hit my phone? Help me please? Her Majesty’s Prison? Human Microbiome Project?

Comment: @Emil Hot Meta Posts

Comment: Seems Catija manually removed the tag the day after you asked this question. Have you seen this be a more widespread issue on other questions? (Could this issue be connected to who adds the tag in the first place, i.e. whether they're SE staff?)

Comment: Just going to add another example that [this meta post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/4484/timeline) was featured on Dec 11 but removed on 15 Jan (35 days).

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. I think that's the system working as intended. The script that removes the tag after 30 days runs once a week every Saturday. There have been [more recent issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375251/377214) with weekly schedulers failing to run correctly, so I think that's what happened in this case.